# VSCode - keybinding conflicts between Windows and Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VSCode on a Linux (Ubuntu 20.10) and Windows 10 machine. On working through the keybindings on each, I observe the following default out of the box settings:

The command `editor.action.copyLinesUpAction` is mapped on Windows to `Shift+Alt+UpArrow`. The same keybinding, however, on Linux is mapped to `editor.action.insertCursorAbove`.

There could be other examples as well. Is there any documentation of an exhaustive list of such differences in commands for the same keypresses on different operating systems?